# Prove that $\sqrt{a^2+3b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+3c^2}+\sqrt{c^2+3a^2}\geq6$ if $(a+b+c)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)=27$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers such that $(a+b+c)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)=27$. Prove that:
$$\sqrt{a^2+3b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+3c^2}+\sqrt{c^2+3a^2}\geq6$$

A big problem here around $(a,b,c)=(1.6185...,0.71686...,0.4926...)$.

In this case we get $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2+3b^2}-6=0.000563...$.

My trying.

Let $a^2+3b^2=4x^2$, $b^2+3c^2=4y^2$ and $c^2+3a^2=4z^2$, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are non-negatives.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{x^2-3y^2+9z^2}\leq\frac{\sqrt7(x+y+z)^2}{\sqrt{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)}}$$

Let $k$ and $m$ be non-negatives, for which

$x-ky+mz>0$, $y-kz+mx>0$, $z-kx+my>0$ and $1-k+m>0$.

By C-S $\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{x^2-3y^2+9z^2}\right)^2\leq(1-k+m)(x+y+z)\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^2-3y^2+9z^2}{x-ky+mz}$.

Thus, it remains to prove that
$$(1-k+m)\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^2-3y^2+9z^2}{x-ky+mz}\leq\frac{7(x+y+z)^3}{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$$

It's a sixth degree, but I didn't find a values of $k$ and $m$, such that the last inequality will be true.

By this way we can prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2+2b^2}\geq3\sqrt3$ is true, but it's not comforting.

Also I tried to use Holder, but without success.

Thank you!

Comment: @Roby5 You are true, I forget a square. I delete my answer, thank you very much

Comment: You skip a lot of details in your substitution which makes it impossible to follow your question without first redoing your calculations.

Comment: @Tara What exactly  I skipped?

Comment: I think this can help you with the condition of the beginning : $$6 \leq\sqrt{a^2+1.5(b^2+c^2)}+\sqrt{2(b^2+c^2)}+\sqrt{0.5(b^2+c^2)+3a²}$$

Comment: I have two inequalities for you with the condition of the beginning we have :  $$6 \leq \sqrt{a^2+1.5((b-\epsilon)^2+(c+\epsilon)^2)}+\sqrt{2((b-\epsilon)^2+(c+\epsilon)^2)}+\sqrt{0.5((b-\epsilon)^2+(c+\epsilon)^2)+3a^2}$$
And 
$$6 \leq \sqrt{a^2+1.5((b-\epsilon)^2+(c+\epsilon)^2)}+\sqrt{2((b-\phi)^2+(c+\phi)^2)}+\sqrt{0.5((b-\beta)^2+(c+\beta)^2)+3a^2}$$

With :
$\epsilon,\beta,\phi\geq0$

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be bugs in the segment after where I marked "***". Needed for check.
 
When I saw the form $\sqrt{a^2+3b^2}$ I thought of the absolute value of a complex number.
So let
$$u=a+\sqrt{3}bi$$
$$v=b+\sqrt{3}ci$$
$$w=c+\sqrt{3}ai$$
And now what you want to prove becomes 
$$|u|+|v|+|w|\geq6$$


$$u+v+w=(1+\sqrt{3}i)(a+b+c)$$
$$|u|^2+|v|^2+|w|^2=4(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$

$$(u+v+w)^2(|u|^2+|v|^2+|w|^2)$$
$$=(1+\sqrt{3}i)^2(a+b+c)^2\cdot4(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$
$$=4(1+\sqrt{3}i)^2(a+b+c)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$
$$=4(1+\sqrt{3}i)^2\cdot27$$

$$|u+v+w|^2(|u|^2+|v|^2+|w|^2)=|4(1+\sqrt{3}i)^2\cdot27|=4\cdot27\cdot4$$
Now I thought I should separate $|u+v+w|$ to $|u|+|v|+|w|$ so that all the elements in the expression were independent $|u|$, $|v|$, $|w|$, and its form would be closer to the inequality we want to prove.
So I used the triangle inequality,
$$|u|+|v|+|w|\geq|u+v|+|w|\geq|u+v+w|$$
$$(|u|+|v|+|w|)^2(|u|^2+|v|^2+|w|^2)\geq|u+v+w|^2(|u|^2+|v|^2+|w|^2)=4\cdot27\cdot4$$
Let $x=|u|,\ \ y=|v|,\ \ z=|w|$
Then the problem becomes,
$$\mathrm{if\ \ }(x+y+z)^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq4\cdot27\cdot4$$
$$\mathrm{prove\ that\ \ }x+y+z\geq6$$
Proof:
let $k$ be a number so that $x+y+z\geq k\geq0$ is always true.
A known formula:
$$(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2=3(x^2+y^2+z^2)-(x+y+z)^2\geq0$$
***Then
$$3(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq(x+y+z)^2\geq k^2$$
$$\implies (x+y+z)^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq k^2\cdot\frac{k^2}{3}=\frac{k^4}{3}$$
But it's already known that $(x+y+z)^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq4\cdot27\cdot4$ has to be true. So to let $$(x+y+z)^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq\frac{k^4}{3}$$ be always true,
$$\frac{k^4}{3}\leq4\cdot27\cdot4$$
$$k\leq6$$
This proof doesn't need $a,b,c\geq0$. It just needs them to be real numbers.

Comment: you mean (a,b,c)=(1.6185...,0.71686...,0.4926...)?

Comment: If you mean the orginal statement, yes I did. But I didn't directly deal with the original problem. I simplified the original problem into another, yet still equivalent. If there's anything that is wrong or confuses you, please tell me.

Comment: It IS a proof! Ok, if the starting problem is called A, another problem is called B, then what I did was I proved that A is EQUIVALENT to B, so I just had to solve problem B.

Comment: You wrote: "If $(x+y+z)^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq4\cdot27\cdot4$
prove that $x+y+z\geq6$". I think, your statement is wrong. Try $y=z=0$ and $x=\sqrt[4]{4\cdot27\cdot4}$.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Let me think more

Comment: Thank you for your interest!

Comment: I think I know the problem. It's confusing to set $|u|$, $|v|$, $|w|$ as $x$, $y$, $z$, because $|u|$, $|v|$, $|w|$ are NOT independent of each other. You said $y=z=0$ and $x=\sqrt[4]{4\cdot27\cdot4}$ will violate that $x+y+z\geq6$. However, $y=|v|=0$, $z=|w|=0$ $\implies b=0,c=0$ and $c=0,a=0$. So $x=|u|=\sqrt{a^2+3b^2}$ can only be 0.