# Three little inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math

after a long reflection on an inequality by Michael Rozenberg ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1857856/prove-that-sqrta23b2-sqrtb23c2-sqrtc23a2-geq6-if-abc2)) I show you my strategy :
In fact the frame of the proof is based on three inequalities :
Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers such that $(a+b+c)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)=27$ and $a\geq c\geq b$ . So we have 
 $$6 \leq\sqrt{a^2+1.5(b^2+c^2)}+\sqrt{2(b^2+c^2)}+\sqrt{0.5(b^2+c^2)+3a²}=F(a,b,c)$$(I) 
$$6 \leq F(a,b,c)\leq \sqrt{a^2+1.5((b-\epsilon)^2+(c+\epsilon)^2)}+\sqrt{2((b-\epsilon)^2+(c+\epsilon)^2)}+\sqrt{0.5((b-\epsilon)^2+(c+\epsilon)^2)+3a^2}$$(II)

And $$6 \leq \sqrt{a^2+1.5((b-\epsilon)^2+(c+\epsilon)^2)}+\sqrt{2((b-\phi)^2+(c+\phi)^2)}+\sqrt{0.5((b-\beta)^2+(c+\beta)^2)+3a^2}$$(III)

With : $\epsilon,\beta,\phi\geq0$

The idea is to build more and more a solution based on the inequality (I)
But I can't prove it , if you have some hints , that would be cool :)
Thanks a lot !