# $\sum\limits_{cyc} \sqrt{a^2+3b^2}\geq \sqrt{12(a+b+c)}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$; $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$. Prove that:
$$\sum\limits_{cyc} \sqrt{a^2+3b^2}\geq \sqrt{12(a+b+c)}$$
I have got stuck at this problem. Any soluion is welcome.

Comment: What is the $\sum$ in the left hand side?

Comment: It is ''Sigma'' sum of numbers in the form $\sqrt{a^2+3b^2}$

Comment: Yes, You're right

Comment: It's known unsolved problem See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1857856

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg what do you mean by **known unsolved problem** as it does not have a solution worldwide ??

Comment: @Ahmad Yes, without computer of course. With computer even I can prove it.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg this is strange, how is it unsolved without computer but with computer its solve-able , i know that if something is proved using computer like the 4 color theorem , its a proof .

Comment: @Ahmad We know the "equality case" and by Holder we can delete radicals and by Buffalo Way we can end the proof. By the way, WA does not help (WA says only that it's true). We need a  powerful computer.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg thanks, but since you are good with such question try to divide it into cases and prove it partially or even a complete proof, for example and again i am not good at these questions but like to try any way i could prove by simple math that when $0 \leq a \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \geq c \geq b \geq a$  the inequality is true.

Comment: @Ahmad There are very many partial proofs, but we have no a full proof.