# Prove that: $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{(b+c)^2+a^2}\leq \frac{3}{5}$

Tags: inequality, tangent-line-method

Given three positive numbers a,b,c satisfying $a+b+c=3$. Show that  $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{(b+c)^2+a^2}\leq \frac{3}{5}$

Things I have done so far:
$$a+b+c=3\Rightarrow b+c=3-a;0<a<3$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{(b+c)^2+a^2}=\frac{1}{(3-a)^2+a^2}=\frac{1}{2(a-1)^2+7-2a}\leq \frac{1}{7-2a}$$
Then, I tried to use the UCT to solve this problem.
I created the new inequality:
$$\frac{1}{7-2a}\leq \frac{1}{5}+m.(a-1)(*)$$
with $0<a<3$. I needed to find "m" which make (*) always true.After that, I found $$m=\frac{2}{25}$$
However, 
$$(*)\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{7-2a}\leq \frac{1}{5}+\frac{2}{25}.(a-1)\Leftrightarrow 4(a-1)^{2}\leq 0$$
which is wrong with any $$a\in \mathbb{R} $$
Can you show me what my mistake is?
I hope you can have "smart" way to solve this problem.
Sorry, I am not good at English.

Comment: Add the source of the inequality (which competition, problem book, ..) and if possible, which methods you expect to need to prove it (e.g. if it appeared as an exercise in a section about Cauchy-Schwarz), or expected difficulty.

Comment: @barto My friend asked me to solve that problem without suggestions so I don't know the source of the inequality.
.

Comment: @ShizumiAoki: this site is not really intended for posts of random problems like this, particularly if they have no source or motivation. In general, if all you can post is a problem statement, and your only source is "a friend", you are probably better off using a different website.

Comment: On the triangle given by $x+y+z=3$ and $x,y,z\geq 0$ the maximum of $\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x^2+(3-x)^2}$ can be found by Lagrange multipliers. $(1,1,1)$ is the only stationary point in the interior of the domain and the behaviour on the boundary is simple to study. Or you may prove that by replacing both $a$ and $b$ with their average the value of the function to maximize increases.

Comment: What is UCT method? ${}$

Comment: @Ovi UCT means "Underfined Coefficient Technique". I don't have any documents about UCT written in English so I don't know how to explain what it is to make you understand.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question, Could you please also add the source of the problem and some motivation for why it is of interest?

Comment: @Carl Mummert My friend said that it was in an magazine about Mathematics. Could it be seen as the source of the problem?

Comment: @ShizumiAoki: if the only source is that you heard the problem from a friend, and you don't have any other motivation for the problem, it may not be a very good fit for this site. This is not a puzzle-solving site, but there are other sites that look for problems of this sort.

Comment: @Carl Mummert Is it necessary to have another motivation for the problem? I think, I have to solve this problem for my friend because she don't know how to solve it. And it is my motivation for the problem.

Comment: @ShizumiAoki: on this site, we look for problems that do have more motivation than just being a puzzle. Is there an application of this inequality? Is it related to other topics in mathematics?  If it was only invented as a puzzle, it probably is not a good fit on this site.

Comment: @CarlMummert Ok, thank you.

Comment: @Carl Mummert is this restriction written down somewhere? The site tour includes "Solving mathematical puzzles" in the list of suitable questions. I have seen many interesting questions motivated only by idle curiosity, and well-received questions similar to this one (eg https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1857856).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the Tangent Line method.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(3-a)^2+a^2}\leq\frac{3}{5}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{2a^2-6a+9}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2-3a+2}{2a^2-6a+9}\geq0$$ or 
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2-3a+2}{2a^2-6a+9}+\frac{1}{5}(a-1)\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-1)^2(2a+1)}{2a^2-6a+9}\geq0$$ and we are done!

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{(b+c)^2+a^2} \le \dfrac{2}{25}(a+b+c)+\dfrac{9}{25}=\dfrac{3}{5}$$

$$\dfrac{1}{(b+c)^2+a^2}=\dfrac{1}{(3-a)^2+a^2}\le \dfrac{2}{25}a+\dfrac{3}{25}\ ,  (a\ge 0)$$